# loginAs() using different database for user sometimes works and sometimes fail

Tags: laravel-dusk

In the application I'm testing the user is being created or fetched from a different database connection. My problem is `loginAs()` seems like unstable with this setup and mostly it works but sometimes it failed to login the user I'm passing and the page I'm visiting is redirecting me to login page as if no one was logged in. Here's an example of how I visit a page using `loginAs()`:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($user) {
    $browser->loginAs($user)
        ->visit('/dashboard')
        ->waitForLocation('/dashboard')
        ->assertPathIs('/dashboard');
});
```

Sometimes the test failed for waiting for the location `/dashboard` because the page was being redirected to `/login`

I tried to print in the console the `$user` variable to see if it's null when the test failed but it is always has some data and yet the error still occurs. I also tried to add `assertAuthenticatedAs($user)` to see if what happens after `loginAs()` in my surprise there is no authenticated user with errors like this:

```
The currently authenticated user is not who was expected.
Failed asserting that null is identical to Array &0 (
    'id' => 1
    'className' => 'App\User'
)
```

So eventhough the `$user` is not null the `loginAs()` failed to login the user. (NOT ALL THE TIME)

Tried searching solution for this issue and I came across with this [thread in github](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/408) but looks like it's still unsolved.

Hope someone can give some inputs on how to solve this.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but this is only happening in CI. Locally the tests never fail